# Intermediate field extensions

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive 12th-root of unity. How many field extensions are there between $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta^3)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$?

Here is my solution:

$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is the splitting field of $X^{12}-1$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension. The minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{12}$, whose degree is 4, therefore $G(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Z}_{12}^*$. Then,  every non trivial subgroup has order 2, so every intermediate extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}$ is quadratic, which shows that there is no intermediate field extensions between $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta^3)$ et $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.

I would like to know if my reasoning is right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as you are confident in that $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta^3)$ is neither of the end points, then, yes, this is one way to conclude.

Comment: What do you mean by "end points"?

Comment: The fields $L=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$ and $K=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta^3)$ themselves could be called the end points of $L/K$. If I were a teacher who assigned this as an exercise I would probably insist that a full solution include an argument as to why $L\neq K$, when the "interval" from $K$ to $L$ would have two end points rather than just one :-) Sorry about being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Since $[Q(ζ):Q)]=|Z_{12}^*|=4$ and $[Q(ζ^3):Q)]=2$, then we get $[Q(ζ):Q(ζ^3))]=2$ and hence your reasons are right.